# Rpi Zero heat a lot ( 200°C in 5 min ) but don't boot

Tags: pi-zero

It was working without problem. I've just forget it a night and it stay work. After this, it no longer boot but heat a lot... This is not the SD... And the cable work perfectly. But the 3.3V pin is at 1.80V. Does everyone have the same problem ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Where are you getting these values from? 200°C is highly unlikely and borders unsoldering the SoC from the PCB not to mention safe operational temperatures of all components.

Answer (score 3):

> 200°C

I don't know how you're measuring that, but it is well beyond the maximum recommended operating temperature of 85°C and implies the SoC is now garbage.

> Does everyone have the same problem ?

No, I've never seen one get above 55-60°C, and that's by maxing the processor core out for a while.  In fact except for the model 3, I don't think I've seen one exceed the bottom end of that range.

> But the 3.3V pin is at 1.80V.

Also not good.  As a random, unexpert guess, perhaps the 3.3V regulator is busted (you did not say which part on the board was getting that hot).  That cannot be fixed.

> How to solve it ?

I think you are out of luck.  Although I doubt it is the case, you could leave it unplugged for a few days on the chance that it is the main [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) that's heating up (but I do not think the symptoms of that would be as you describe).

Comment: ... or as we say: This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker!

Comment: @Ghanima Perhaps it is only pining for the fjords.

Comment: 200 celcius at 5 volts man this guys Pi must be the worlds most efficient space heater as my oven needs 1500 watts to get that warm and not the 10 that the Pi uses. Pretty sure that places it at over 100% efficiency

Comment: Bootiful bird, that Norwegian Blue, but the only reason 'E was staying on the perch was because 'E was bleeding _nailed_ to it... likewise I fink your RPi has _joined the Choir Eternal and shuffled of this mortal coil!_  A low voltage on the power supply rail can be because the limited 3.3V has been dragged down to only 1 and a bit volts because of ___excessive___ numbers of electrons sneaking through the SoC (or something else) and generating the heat (as they do).  Pardon me for seeming a bit personal but do you have a liking for synthetic fabrics?

Comment: ... The reason for asking is that (Electro-)Static damage might be a cause here, those GPIO pins are quite close (electrically) to the SoC and I do wonder how many RPis get more than unpleasant electric shocks from their owners and subsequently develop issues (and it can be a very long time later) from damage to their internals from a static discharge into one or more pins.